# Fix for the message 'We are no longer accepting answers from this account'

Tags: support, post-ban

Trying to answer a question, I'm getting the message 'We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.'

It happens that I had a SINGLE post, and it was deleted because somebody considered it not being very informative, so I EDITED it, but it remains deleted, and it's like this post is causing me not to be able to answer questions...

This happens to me on different ips, and I'm not able to find the reason.

How can I completely delete that answer of mine? I cannot even upvote anything.

I think that this system is so bad 'banning' people this way, without making it clear why you have been banned. Lots of people are 'duplicating' my question, and I do it again being as frustrated as I am. Believe me, I've been participating in lots of tech forums and this is the first time I'm being banned. And what a way to do it!

Right now I cannot completely delete it, and the editing remains unuseful too, as I cannot undelete it, either.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can flag the post and ask a moderator to undelete it. Giving a link to it here would also help (3 community members above a certain threshold can undelete). But are you sure you only have *one* deleted answer? (I can't count how many banned users made the same claim, then later said "Oh, I forgot about all those other deleted posts...")

Comment: ... to add to Davids comment you can flag one of your questions as needing moderator attention, and ask them to undelete any posts you have deleted. You then have the opportunity to fix those forgotten-about posts.

Comment: @Matt He has no other questions at all (at least not visible) currently.

Comment: @Matt It doesn't sound like it's self-deleted though; it sounds mod deleted.

Comment: @ypercube Not being a mod, you can't know how many deleted questions he has.

Comment: That's what I said. "Not visible" to us, mere mortals.

Comment: @Servy 10kers can see them too.

Comment: @Undo 10kers can see them if they have a link, they can't know how many deleted questions a user has if they don't have a link to them all, only a mod can see the listing of all deleted questions for a user.

Comment: @Servy The `user:xxxxxxxx deleted:1` search won't work?

Comment: @Undo Nope. (by design)

Comment: @Servy: I'm as sceptical as David about the OP only having one deleted post. I've never, *ever* heard of the ban kicking into play so early.

Comment: @Matt: where's a moderator when you need one?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to look at [this FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers).

**Second**, Stack Overflow is *not* your average tech forum - mainly because we aren't a forum.

We're a question and answer site. No distractions. Just Q&A.

I'm not a mod, so I can't see your deleted posts. However, I can tell you that we require *much* higher quality than your average tech forum. You should flag one of your posts and ask a moderator to undelete anything you have deleted - deleted stuff is one the highest factors for getting automatically banned.