# I just answered a closed question

Tags: bug, closed-questions, timestamps

I saw [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187036/215468), and voted to close it as the dupe that it is.

However, one thing that the author wrote caught my eye:

> Believe me, I've been participating in lots of tech forums and this is the first time I'm being banned.

So, I wrote up an explanation of how SO isn't a tech forum.

I hurried, because I knew the post was going to get closed.

It did, of course. But this?:

[image: closed]

[image]

Uhh... `44 > 32`. **I answered a question 12 seconds *after* it was closed**.

If this isn't a bug, nothing is.

Comment: *"If this isn't a bug, nothing is."* - Woohoo! No more bugs!

Comment: @animuson **I just answered a closed question**. You can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, this happens when you're already in the process of answering before it is closed. I think it has something to do with already having a draft saved for your answer, but I'm not 100% on that.

<strike>That said; *please* do not use answers in that manner. That is not an answer, and should be a comment, instead.</strike> Eek! I didn't notice the question was posted on Meta! Ignore the above!

Comment: OK, I understand. Thanks! **But:** Previously, I think that the system wouldn't allow you to submit your answer.

Comment: @Undo  See the duplicate, which is pretty old. Nothing's changed there. At times, it seems random, because it's not a simple trigger than enables what you did.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, actually that is an appropriate answer for that type of question on META.

Comment: @Undo, I have no dog in this fight, but right is right.

Comment: @Andrew Now I'm just confused... This *is* Meta, right?

Comment: @LanceRoberts I didn't even *notice* that question was posted on Meta! Yikes!

Comment: @Undo I didn't realize that question was posted on Meta at all. Silly me!

Comment: @Andrew Going color blind? :)

Comment: So just to clarify: The answer is OK, right?

Comment: @Undo Looks absolutely fine to me, yes.